# Function-based index behavior when function depends on data from another (not the one on which the index was created) table

Tags: sql, oracle, indexing, plsql

I'm trying to understand how to work properly with [function-based index](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_5010.htm) if function depends on data from another (not the one on which the index was created) table.

Suppose, I have the following test data:

```
SQL> drop table table_with_data;
   2 drop table table_test_a;
   3 drop table table_test_b;
   4
   5 create table table_with_data (data_id integer, val1 number);
   6 create table table_test_a (val1 number, val2 varchar2(100));
   7 create table table_test_b (val1 number, val2 varchar2(100));
   8
   9 insert into table_with_data values (1,1);
  10 insert into table_with_data values (10,2);
  11 insert into table_with_data values (30,3);
  12
  13 insert into table_test_b values (1, 'one');
  14 insert into table_test_b values (20, 'two');
  15 insert into table_test_b values (30, 'three');
  16
  17 insert into table_test_a values (1, 'first');
  18 insert into table_test_a values (2, 'second');
  19 insert into table_test_a values (3, 'third');
```

Also, I have defined a function:

```
SQL> create or replace function test_func(val_in number) 
   2 return number deterministic as
   3 output number;
   4  begin 
   5   select val1 
   6   into output
   7   from table_with_data
   8   where data_id = val_in;
   9
  10   return output;
  11  end;
```

To speed up such query

```
SQL> select a.*, (select b.val2 
   2              from table_test_b b
   3              where test_func(b.val1) = a.val1)
   4  from table_test_a a;
```

I've decided to use [function-based index](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_5010.htm)

```
SQL> create index test_func_indx on table_test_b(test_func(val1));
```

And it works fine.

But if one will update a value in table_with_data

```
SQL> update table_with_data set data_id = 20 where val1 = 2;
```

Output of mentioned above query does not change.

Is there any proper way to update function-based index if function depends on data from another table?

Or maybe there are other ways to construct function-based index in this case?

Comment: @nikhilsugandh Can you tell me more clearly where I should declare val1? I will fix it. In function test_func val1 is part of select ... into clause and as I understand it shouldn't be declared.

Comment: my bad!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 2):

Only functions that always return the same result for the same parameters—functions that are deterministic—can be indexed.That is why updating  function-based index if function depends on data from another table is invalid and null.
Besides being deterministic, PostgreSQL and the Oracle database require functions to be declared to be deterministic when used in an index so you have to use the keyword DETERMINISTIC (Oracle) or IMMUTABLE (PostgreSQL).

but if you update table_with_data its not deterministic anymore

```
update table_with_data set data_id = 1 where val1 = 2;
```

and oracle does not allow a non deterministic function based index on user defined functions.